# Ways for saying Sudden Idea

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I need help to find some idioms on creating a sudden idea, so I thought, why not, ask the question? So I'm gonna write down the ones I already know and then ask you guys to write yours...

*Popped into my mind*

*An "Aha!" moment*

*Hit me in the face like a thunderstorm*

Comment: Shadow: welcome to the site. You pose an interesting request; but I am not sure it is the type of question that is a good fit for this site. Others here may disagree. But do note that the tag for **phrase requests** states "Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered." Please help improve your question by including this information.

Comment: Also, kindly note that this is not a "brain storming" site.... and that questions are expected to indicate research. Please take a tour of the site and visit the Help Center to see what type of questions are on-topic.

Comment: While I'm a proponent of finding ideal words or phrases, I'm afraid in this particular case there isn't a *specific* one that you're looking for that would be the best fit. Asking *just* for a list isn't something that's as focused as it should be here. If you can isolate some criteria that could clearly point to a *single* answer that people could aim for, that would be better.

Comment: *Like a bolt from the blue*.

Answer (score 3):

As a native speaker of North American English, the first phrase that came to mind for me was epiphany.

Merriam Webster defines epiphany as:

> epiphany - noun - epiph·a·ny  \ i-ˈpi-fə-nē \ - an illuminating discovery,
>   realization, or disclosure

[Source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epiphany)

As in, "I've had an epiphany!"

Others to consider: "Eureka!" and "Break-through"

Comment: "Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered." I am talking about the question. Why provide an answer to a question that is not well-formulated? If you are trying to help the user, write a comment; don't indulge them with an answer to a question that does not meet site standards. See recent questions in Meta.

Comment: I can't have two webpages open at once on my handheld.  I needed to save and edit with my source.

Comment: Yes, I know. Which is why I said I am not referring to your answer; I was referring to the question. It does not include necessary information to make it an on-topic question.

Comment: No offense, but I'll leave that up to you for tonight.  I've already gone through the LQP queue enough times today.  I don't know about you, but I find it exhausting, constantly telling people that they are doing things wrong.

Comment: Yup. To me, the problem is the disconnect (in the site) between the site's invitation to ask a question about EL&U and what the Help Center says are actually on-topic questions.